# Use a boolean in a For Loop

Tags: python, python-requests, boolean, python-3.10

I have a Script that sends a Notification to my Phone using ntfy.

It pings a Device and if the Ping responds with an Error, it sends a Notification to my Phone.

```py
for ip in ap_ips:
    try:
        ping3.ping(ip)
        requests.post(ntfy_adress,
                      data=("Das Gerät mit der IP-Adresse " + ip + " ist online.").encode(
                          encoding='utf-8'),
                      headers={
                          "Title": ("Unifi AP ist Online!"),
                      })
    except:
        requests.post(ntfy_adress,
                      data=("Das Gerät mit der IP-Adresse " + ip + " ist nicht mehr erreichbar.").encode(encoding='utf-8'),
                      headers={
                          "Title": ("Unifi AP ist Offline!"),
                          "Tags": "warning"
                      })
```

The Script is supposed to be running in a infinite Loop.

How do i get the Script to only send a Notification if the Ping Result is diffrent than before?

Comment: You shouldn't use a blanket except, especially since it encompasses more lines than you want. Now if your `post` fails you will get a message the server is offline which it is not

Comment: Im already looking into it. Thanks.

Comment: `str` is a keyword in python. Better not to use it for variable names.

Comment: Already fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store between two executions the status. Before your while loop do something like:

```py
status = {}
```

And then, check that the previous status is not the current one

```py
for ip in ap_ips:
    try:
        ping3.ping(ip)

        if status.get(ip) != "OK":
            requests.post(
                ntfy_adress,
                data=("Das Gerät mit der IP-Adresse " + ip + " ist online.").encode(
                    encoding="utf-8"
                ),
                headers={
                    "Title": ("Unifi AP ist Online!"),
                },
            )
        status[ip] = "OK"

    except:  # You should set explicitly which error type you expect here if ping fails.
        if status.get(ip) != "KO":
            requests.post(
                ntfy_adress,
                data=(
                    "Das Gerät mit der IP-Adresse " + ip + " ist nicht mehr erreichbar."
                ).encode(encoding="utf-8"),
                headers={"Title": ("Unifi AP ist Offline!"), "Tags": "warning"},
            )
        status[ip] = "KO"
```